# PlayWS post multipart form data

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I'm trying to post a file and some data to Mailgun using PlayWS but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot write an instance of akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.Part[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString, Any]], Any] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData.Part[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString, Any]], Any]]
```

The code looks like this:

```
def ws(url: String) = 
  wsClient.url(s"${url}").withAuth("api", apiKey, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)

ws(url).post(Source(
  FilePart("test", "test.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromFile(file)) :: 
  DataPart("key", "value") :: 
  List()))
```

I know what the error is asking me to do, but I don't know how to implement a `Writable` for a `Source` in this case. Isn't this something that should have a predefined implementation?

Comment: Could you share your imports in your code? I'm trying to do what you're doing and I'm having trouble making the Source for the post in such a way that it doesn't tell me to create a Writeable. Using 2.5.12

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented, but only in 2.5.1+

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is only implemented starting from Play **2.6.x** (specifically [here, play-ws](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/blob/master/play-ws-standalone/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/DefaultBodyWritables.scala)).

There are workarounds for Play 2.5.x though!

[As documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Streaming-data):

- To stream a `Source`, you need to enclose it within `StreamBody`, [as in](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Streaming-data):

`val wsResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(url)
   .withBody(StreamedBody(largeImageFromDB)).execute("PUT")`

- [To stream a MultiPart/form data](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-multipart/form-data):

`ws.url(url).post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromFile(tmpFile)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))`